# How do I add a master node to the same ElasticSearch cluster within one server?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two Elasticsearch nodes installed as tar on the server and running on ports 9200 and 9201.

I would like to have both master nodes running as the same cluster.

Each is running fine, but clustering is not working.

The following is the network setting of my elasticsearch.yml file.

## NODE-1

```
cluster.name: My-ElasticSearch

node.name: "node-1"

node.roles: [ master,data ]

network.host: 10.0.20.10

http.port: 9200

transport.port: 9300

discovery.seed_hosts: ["10.0.20.10:9300", "10.0.20.10:9301"]

cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]

http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"

transport.host: 10.0.20.10
```

node-1 run log

```
[2022-09-27T00:47:12,272][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [node-1] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv)]], net usable_space [75.9gb], net total_space [94.9gb], types [ext4]
[2022-09-27T00:47:12,272][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [node-1] heap size [3.8gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2022-09-27T00:47:12,315][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-1] node name [node-1], node ID [IHal4DVSRCaUes8HN-VWjA], cluster name [My-ElasticSearch], roles [data, master]
[2022-09-27T00:47:14,805][INFO ][o.e.x.s.Security         ] [node-1] Security is disabled
[2022-09-27T00:47:14,851][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [node-1] [controller/1758] [Main.cc@123] controller (64 bit): Version 8.3.3 (Build d2d2e518384d45) Copyright (c) 2022 Elasticsearch BV
[2022-09-27T00:47:15,193][INFO ][o.e.t.n.NettyAllocator   ] [node-1] creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=elasticsearch_configured, chunk_size=1mb, suggested_max_allocation_size=1mb, factors={es.unsafe.use_netty_default_chunk_and_page_size=false, g1gc_enabled=true, g1gc_region_size=4mb}]
[2022-09-27T00:47:15,214][INFO ][o.e.i.r.RecoverySettings ] [node-1] using rate limit [40mb] with [default=40mb, read=0b, write=0b, max=0b]
[2022-09-27T00:47:15,240][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [node-1] using discovery type [multi-node] and seed hosts providers [settings]
[2022-09-27T00:47:16,286][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-1] initialized
[2022-09-27T00:47:16,287][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-1] starting ...
[2022-09-27T00:47:16,306][INFO ][o.e.x.s.c.f.PersistentCache] [node-1] persistent cache index loaded
[2022-09-27T00:47:16,307][INFO ][o.e.x.d.l.DeprecationIndexingComponent] [node-1] deprecation component started
[2022-09-27T00:47:16,486][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [node-1] publish_address {10.0.20.10:9300}, bound_addresses {10.0.20.10:9300}
[2022-09-27T00:47:17,110][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [node-1] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2022-09-27T00:47:17,114][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterBootstrapService] [node-1] this node is locked into cluster UUID [YsU25ZUuQRqZNUG3YykAjg] but [cluster.initial_master_nodes] is set to [node-1, node-2]; remove this setting to avoid possible data loss caused by subsequent cluster bootstrap attempts
[2022-09-27T00:47:17,236][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [node-1] elected-as-master ([1] nodes joined)[_FINISH_ELECTION_, {node-1}{IHal4DVSRCaUes8HN-VWjA}{qc71eyIPTjS_SIckpcdmgg}{node-1}{10.0.20.10}{10.0.20.10:9300}{dm} completing election], term: 24, version: 996, delta: master node changed {previous [], current [{node-1}{IHal4DVSRCaUes8HN-VWjA}{qc71eyIPTjS_SIckpcdmgg}{node-1}{10.0.20.10}{10.0.20.10:9300}{dm}]}
[2022-09-27T00:47:17,290][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [node-1] master node changed {previous [], current [{node-1}{IHal4DVSRCaUes8HN-VWjA}{qc71eyIPTjS_SIckpcdmgg}{node-1}{10.0.20.10}{10.0.20.10:9300}{dm}]}, term: 24, version: 996, reason: Publication{term=24, version=996}
[2022-09-27T00:47:17,328][INFO ][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] [node-1] publish_address {10.0.20.10:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}
[2022-09-27T00:47:17,328][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-1] started {node-1}{IHal4DVSRCaUes8HN-VWjA}{qc71eyIPTjS_SIckpcdmgg}{node-1}{10.0.20.10}{10.0.20.10:9300}{dm}{xpack.installed=true}
```

node-1 state

```
ubuntu@elasticsearch:~$ curl http://10.0.20.10:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
{
  "cluster_name" : "My-ElasticSearch",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 17,
  "active_shards" : 17,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 4,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 80.95238095238095
}
```

## NODE-2

```
cluster.name: My-ElasticSearch

node.name: node-2

node.roles: [ master ]

network.bind_host: 10.0.20.10

network.host: 10.0.20.10

network.publish_host: 10.0.20.10

http.port: 9201

transport.port: 9301

discovery.seed_hosts: ["10.0.20.10:9300", "10.0.20.10:9301"]

cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]

http.host: 10.0.20.10

http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
```

node-2 run log

```
[2022-09-27T00:53:20,372][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [node-2] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv)]], net usable_space [75.9gb], net total_space [94.9gb], types [ext4]
[2022-09-27T00:53:20,372][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [node-2] heap size [4.6gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2022-09-27T00:53:20,429][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-2] node name [node-2], node ID [PSaq7WA5RvSJduF-9Uk-KA], cluster name [My-ElasticSearch], roles [master]
[2022-09-27T00:53:23,022][INFO ][o.e.x.s.Security         ] [node-2] Security is disabled
[2022-09-27T00:53:23,085][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [node-2] [controller/1995] [Main.cc@123] controller (64 bit): Version 8.3.3 (Build d2d2e518384d45) Copyright (c) 2022 Elasticsearch BV
[2022-09-27T00:53:23,506][INFO ][o.e.t.n.NettyAllocator   ] [node-2] creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=elasticsearch_configured, chunk_size=1mb, suggested_max_allocation_size=1mb, factors={es.unsafe.use_netty_default_chunk_and_page_size=false, g1gc_enabled=true, g1gc_region_size=4mb}]
[2022-09-27T00:53:23,531][INFO ][o.e.i.r.RecoverySettings ] [node-2] using rate limit [40mb] with [default=40mb, read=0b, write=0b, max=0b]
[2022-09-27T00:53:23,560][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [node-2] using discovery type [multi-node] and seed hosts providers [settings]
[2022-09-27T00:53:24,634][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-2] initialized
[2022-09-27T00:53:24,635][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-2] starting ...
[2022-09-27T00:53:24,642][INFO ][o.e.x.d.l.DeprecationIndexingComponent] [node-2] deprecation component started
[2022-09-27T00:53:24,765][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [node-2] publish_address {10.0.20.10:9301}, bound_addresses {[::]:9301}
[2022-09-27T00:53:25,039][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [node-2] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2022-09-27T00:53:25,042][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterBootstrapService] [node-2] this node is locked into cluster UUID [IOwpgSpjQYWX4Vr9f-Cx_g] but [cluster.initial_master_nodes] is set to [node-1, node-2]; remove this setting to avoid possible data loss caused by subsequent cluster bootstrap attempts
[2022-09-27T00:53:25,104][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [node-2] elected-as-master ([1] nodes joined)[_FINISH_ELECTION_, {node-2}{PSaq7WA5RvSJduF-9Uk-KA}{q8Ls3l-mR9u0pUJ4STb58w}{node-2}{10.0.20.10}{10.0.20.10:9301}{m} completing election], term: 19, version: 105, delta: master node changed {previous [], current [{node-2}{PSaq7WA5RvSJduF-9Uk-KA}{q8Ls3l-mR9u0pUJ4STb58w}{node-2}{10.0.20.10}{10.0.20.10:9301}{m}]}
[2022-09-27T00:53:25,164][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [node-2] master node changed {previous [], current [{node-2}{PSaq7WA5RvSJduF-9Uk-KA}{q8Ls3l-mR9u0pUJ4STb58w}{node-2}{10.0.20.10}{10.0.20.10:9301}{m}]}, term: 19, version: 105, reason: Publication{term=19, version=105}
[2022-09-27T00:53:25,194][INFO ][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] [node-2] publish_address {10.0.20.10:9201}, bound_addresses {10.0.20.10:9201}
[2022-09-27T00:53:25,195][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-2] started {node-2}{PSaq7WA5RvSJduF-9Uk-KA}{q8Ls3l-mR9u0pUJ4STb58w}{node-2}{10.0.20.10}{10.0.20.10:9301}{m}{xpack.installed=true}
```

node-2 state

```
ubuntu@elasticsearch:~$ curl http://10.0.20.10:9201/_cluster/health?pretty
{
  "cluster_name" : "My-ElasticSearch",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 0,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 2,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 0.0
}
```

All xpack security settings are false.

And below is the result when connecting from head.

[image]

[image]

Why is the node not clustering?
please let me know...TT

(I've edited the question before posting it because I didn't do it well.)

val request curl

```
ubuntu@elasticsearch:~$ curl http://10.0.20.10:9200/
{
  "name" : "node-1",
  "cluster_name" : "My-ElasticSearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "YsU25ZUuQRqZNUG3YykAjg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.3.3",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "801fed82df74dbe537f89b71b098ccaff88d2c56",
    "build_date" : "2022-07-23T19:30:09.227964828Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.2.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
ubuntu@elasticsearch:~$ curl http://10.0.20.10:9201/
{
  "name" : "node-2",
  "cluster_name" : "My-ElasticSearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "IOwpgSpjQYWX4Vr9f-Cx_g",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.3.3",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "801fed82df74dbe537f89b71b098ccaff88d2c56",
    "build_date" : "2022-07-23T19:30:09.227964828Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.2.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: Can you add the response you get from `curl http://10.0.20.10:9200/` and `curl http://10.0.20.10:9201/` ?

Comment: val/ Added to content.

Comment: it looks like you have previously started the 2 nodes independently and they weren't able to cluster? assuming you don't have data in these, I would delete everything, untar one node and set it up, then once it's formed a cluster (voted itself as master) try adding the other node

Comment: Mark Walkom/ 
Thanks i solved it.
 But I want to add nodes after configuring clustering. Is there no such way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed Mark Walkom's method and it worked.

Before starting, you need to set seed_host and initial_master_nodes in advance.

However, when running, I had to run the rest of the nodes within the time limit.

When you run the first node, the following message appears.
Then you need to run the second node.

```
[2022-09-27T07:44:01,557][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [node-1] master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [node-1, node-2] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{node-1}{NBsKhaguTKiH_JNJ6DkRYw}{zmC5Tel1QIWGl1eUq4fLXQ}{node-1}{10.20.0.10}{10.20.0.10:9300}{dm}]; discovery will continue using [10.0.20.10:9300, 10.0.20.10:9301] from hosts providers and [{node-1}{NBsKhaguTKiH_JNJ6DkRYw}{zmC5Tel1QIWGl1eUq4fLXQ}{node-1}{10.20.0.10}{10.20.0.10:9300}{dm}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0
```

But I want to add a node to an already created cluster.

This method is too inconvenient.

If anyone knows how to add a node to an already created cluster, please let me know.

Comment: You can add a new data node easily, but not a new master node, after a cluster has already formed.